# Glide does not load the same thumbnails as the gallery app

Tags: android, android-glide

I have a gallery app where I am loading thumbnails of the videos with glide. The problem is I want the thumbnails to be the same as it is in the original gallery.

```
    fun bind(position: Int) {
        selectedAlbum.mediaList[position].let {
            Glide.with(itemView)
                    .load(it.path)
                    .apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform())
                    .into(itemView.mediaThumbnail)
        }
    }
```

The code above is inside the adapter where I load the video thumbnails. the code is in kotlin and "it" keyword refers to a media object where it.path is the path of the video.

How can I make sure that the thumbnails are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try with Picasso.

```
Picasso.with(context)
   .load(it.path) // thumbnail url goes here
   .into(itemView.mediaThumbnail, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(it.path) // image url goes here
                    .placeholder(imageView.getDrawable())
                    .into(itemView.mediaThumbnail);
        }
        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I cant change the Glide library as this is a requirement from my team

Comment: Just atleast try picasso to see the output. If its working you can move ahead.